# MogoDB subdocument filteration

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e43edb85ed11cd4dcba45"),
        "email" : "av@gmail.com",
        "username" : "alpesh",
        "subscriptions" : [ 
            {
                "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
                "activation_date" : ISODate("2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z")
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
                "activation_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z")
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : "5a51a925ddc5003b68cc38b3",
                "activation_date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T18:30:00.000Z")
            }
        ]
    }
```

i have tried this..
db.find({"subscriptions.sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361" });
it returns ..

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e43edb85ed11cd4dcba45"),
    "email" : "av@gmail.com",
    "username" : "alpesh",
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
            "activation_date" : ISODate("2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
            "activation_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "sub_id" : "5a51a925ddc5003b68cc38b3",
            "activation_date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-03-22T18:30:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

i have also tried $aggregate , $unwind , $filter , $projection and many ways but none of them returns as expected...
i want all the matching subdocuments...like this....

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4e43edb85ed11cd4dcba45"),
        "email" : "av@gmail.com",
        "username" : "alpesh",
        "subscriptions" : [ 
            {
                "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
                "activation_date" : ISODate("2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z")
            }, 
            {
                "sub_id" : "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
                "activation_date" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "expiry_date" : ISODate("2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z")
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Subdocument is `subscriptions` and you are using `subscription.sub_id` ?

Comment: typooss!! corrected...please check..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection('gyms').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            subscriptions: { 
                $elemMatch: { sub_id: "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $or: [
                        { $eq: ["$sub_id", "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361" ] },
                        { $not: "$sub_id" }
                    ]
                },
                then: "$$DESCEND",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

this is generating as expected within a single doucment without unnecessary sub documents.

```
{
    "email": "av@gmail.com",
    "username": "alpesh",
    "subscriptions": [
        {
            "sub_id": "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
            "activation_date": "2017-12-19T18:30:00.000Z",
            "expiry_date": "2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "sub_id": "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361",
            "activation_date": "2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z",
            "expiry_date": "2018-02-19T18:30:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to achieve that. You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) as a projection operator but this will only bring you first matching subdocument:

```
db.collection.find(
    { "subscriptions.sub_id": "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361" },
    { "subscriptions" : { $elemMatch: { "sub_id": "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361" } } }
)
```

Second way is by using aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
    { $unwind: "$subscriptions" },
    { $match: {"subscriptions.sub_id": "5a4df654b9799b79147f9361"} },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            "email" : { $first: "$email" },
            "username" : { $first: "$username" },
            "subscriptions": { $push: "$subscriptions" }
        }
    }
])
```

Here the point is that you need to group back your unwinded subscriptions to get back original shape (after filtering). To retrieve accumulate subscriptions into array you can use `$push` operator and to get back properties from outer document you can move them from any matching document (by using `$first` or `$last`).

Comment: it is not confirmed that there will be only email and username out of subscription..